# 7 Segment Dual Common Anode Connection

Tags: arduino, 7segmentdisplay

I just received this item and I have tried to connect it but I cant seem to find anywhere datasheet for this as all tutorials I have seen, the connections are at the bottom and at the top and in this one is just 10 at the bottom for 2 digits. How do I connect this one?

[image]

Comment: It's not possible to tell you the pinout from an image. Do you have a part number? You can figure out the pinout by applying voltage (with a series resistor or some other form of current limiting) across combinations of pins.

Comment: 16 LEDs 10 Pins?

Comment: @Tyler exactly. Thats why im confused and cant seem to find any info on that. i bought that display from [here](https://m.ebay.co.uk/itm/7-segment-LED-Display-Single-Double-Digit-0-3-0-56-Common-Anode-or-Cathode/231631926172)

Comment: Ask the vendor for a datasheet.  In future, only buy from reputable distributors, who will make datasheets available on their websites.

Comment: Well it was very hard to find the colors i needed and this one had all of them so it was cheaper to buy. I will ask the seller if he has a datasheet

Comment: Chances are it is using multiplexed connections. There is an old saying: Buy the data sheet before you buy the part.

Comment: Which brings us to the **cardinal rule:**  *No datasheet ⇒ No sale*

Comment: @NickAlexeev Bah, that takes all the fun out of buying things at a Chinese market.

Answer (score 3):

The internal schematic will look like this (you will note there are 10 pins):

[image]

Your mission, should you choose to accept it, is to determine which number pins go where. You can do this with a 5V power supply and a 1K resistor in series. Just poke around until you figure it out. Won't take much longer than it did for me to type this. You can't hurt anything if you stick to 5V with the 1K in series.